# typescript warning on destructing alias using withRouter

Tags: typescript

I have a class component written in pure javascript in react:

```
class Auth extends Component {
  render() {
    const { component: Component, ...rest } = this.props //error: Property 'component' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.ts(2339)


    const isAuth = getUser() //some function

    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props =>
          isAuth ? (
            <Component {...props} />
          ) : (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: '/login'
              }}
            />
          )
        }
      />
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(Auth) //error: Argument of type 'typeof Auth' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentClass<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, any>, any> | FunctionComponent<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, any>> | (FunctionComponent<...> & ComponentClass<...>) | (ComponentClass<...> & FunctionComponent<...>)'.
```

But Typescript is throwing warning, what's the problem with my code above?

Comment: `... to parameter of type` - what?

Comment: 1. You need to provide props type to `Component<T>`

Comment: @AlekseyL. it doesn't remove the second error.

Comment: I guess something to do with `RouteComponentProps`

Comment: I just did withRouter<any, any>(Auth) for now, ts suck.